# What's the difference between KotlinNullPointerException and Java's NullPointerException

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception

As Kotlin doesn't allow for implicit null values/variables, was `KotlinNullPointerException` introduced to explicitly denote `NPE` caused by `!!`? Is that the only purpose of this child class of `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 1.3, Kotlin throws `KotlinNullPointerException` only in case of a failed `!!` operator check. This distinguishes it from the other cases where `NullPointerException` can be thrown, for example, when accessing non-initialized members during class construction.

Note, however, that there are plans to remove this distinction in Kotlin 1.4: all such failed checks will throw just `NullPointerException`, so its inheritor `KotlinNullPointerException` will become unused. You can read more about that in the announce blog post of 1.3.50 version release: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/08/kotlin-1-3-50-released/

Answer (score 3):

There is no real difference between a `KotlinNullPointerException` and `JavaNullPointerException`.

Here is how:

`KotlinNullPointerException` is an `open` class that extends `NullPointerException` Now this `NullPointerException` is a `typealias` of `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

```
public open class KotlinNullPointerException : NullPointerException {
  constructor()

  constructor(message: String?) : super(message)
}
```

This is a line extracted from `TypeAlias.Kt`

```
@SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias NullPointerException = java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Now, if we see the declaration of `java.lang.NullPointerException`, we are taken to a `Java.lang` class that extends `RuntimeException`.

```
public
class NullPointerException extends RuntimeException {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 5162710183389028792L;

 /**
  * Constructs a {@code NullPointerException} with no detail message.
  */
 public NullPointerException() {
     super();
 }

 /**
  * Constructs a {@code NullPointerException} with the specified
  * detail message.
  *
  * @param   s   the detail message.
  */
 public NullPointerException(String s) {
     super(s);
 }
}
```

In Kotlin, to make some declaration of nullable type, you have to explicitly allow it by appending `?` at the end of declaration type. Example:

```
var nullableString: String? = null
```

This is a simple way of saying that this variable could be null anytime, so if you try to access this variable from any part of your code, it will throw error and will force you to take measures to prevent `NPE` either using `!!`(crash if null) or `?`(skip if null).
It's just a way to make it look more like 'Kotlin'.

Comment: I believe the question is asking why it was created if there is not difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I find it informative. Maybe I didn't formulate the question properly but I think Ilya's answer below is the one I was looking for.